# nodejs http server: how to end a request when got error?

Tags: node.js

In app.js:

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    require('./ctl/index.js')(req,res)
});
```

In ctl/index.js:

```
module.exports =  async (req,res) => {
    func_not_exists(); // for testing purpose
    res.end("ok");
}
```

After I start the server using `node app.js`, open the url from a web browser, I can get `is not a function` msg from log, but the request process is not end (the web browser icon keep spin). How can I end the user request immediately after got error?

(I'm not using Express.js, but pure http module. I don't want to end whole process using process.exit(), just want to end the current user request.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the request listener as an asynchronous function and use a `try catch` in combination with the `await`:

```
const server = http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
  try {
    await require('./ctl/index.js')(req, res)
  } catch (error) {
    res.end('Something went wrong')
  }
})
```